# How to select number of rows equal to the next set of rows where column is not null? Only for first set of non null rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table like this:

| item | date | discount | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | 11/1/2023 | null | 10 |
| Chair | 11/2/2023 | null | 10 |
| Chair | 11/3/2023 | null | 10 |
| Chair | 11/4/2023 | null | 10 |
| Chair | 11/5/2023 | null | 10 |
| Chair | 11/6/2023 | 0.30 | 10 |
| Chair | 11/7/2023 | 0.30 | 10 |
| Chair | 11/8/2023 | 0.30 | 10 |
| Chair | 11/9/2023 | null | 10 |

I'm able to apply a Gaps and Islands trick to get to most of my desired table:

| item | start_date | end_date | num*of*days | discount | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | 11/1/2023 | 11/5/2023 | 5 | null | 50 |
| Chair | 11/6/2023 | 11/8/2023 | 3 | 0.30 | 30 |
| Chair | 11/9/2023 | 11/9/2023 | 1 | null | 10 |

However, what I really want is **just** the first set of nulls to equal the numofdays as the following set of non-nulls:

| item | start_date | end_date | num*of*days | discount | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | 11/3/2023 | 11/5/2023 | 3 | null | 30 |
| Chair | 11/6/2023 | 11/8/2023 | 3 | 0.30 | 30 |
| Chair | 11/9/2023 | 11/9/2023 | 1 | null | 30 |

The only functions I've thought out using are a combination of `LAG` `LEAD` with `CASE` statements.

Would anyone be able to help with this? It'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `WINDOW` function on your existing Gaps and Island query as follows:

```
WITH CTE as (your existing query having Gaps and Islands trick)
SELECT T.ITEM, T.START_DATE, T.END_DATE,
       CASE WHEN NULL_CHECK = 1 THEN NNOD ELSE NUMOFDAYS END AS NUMOFDAYS
  FROM 
      (SELECT T.*,
              LEAD(NUMOFDAYS) 
                   OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY START_DATE) AS NNOD,
              SUM(CASE WHEN DISCOUNT IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
                   OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY START_DATE) AS NULL_CHECK
         FROM CTE) T;
```

Comment: Thanks you! This achieved what I initially asked, but I realized I didn't accurately ask what I really wanted. The idea is to also get the revenue aggregated the same way (edited the post to reflect this). I'm thinking something has to be done to first table because I'm grouping on the gaps and islands to get the start and end dates.